# Submit Buttons in two different forms go to the same file, they shouldn't

Tags: html

I recently decided to make a little game, and I'm trying to design the first page, to either create an account or go to an existing account. 
Here's what I have:

```
<center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action = "findMyAccount.html" method = "post">
            <input type = "submit" value = 'Login to an Existing Account' />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action = "accountMaker.html" method = "post">
            <input type = "submit" value = 'Make a new Account'/>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

But when I click the **"Make a new Account"** input, it takes me to the *findMyAccount.html* instead of *accountMaker.html*. I'm not sure what's going wrong, I'm still a newbie when it comes to this stuff, so bear with me. Thanks

Comment: it is working for me

Comment: It works for me too. What browser do you use?

Comment: I don't really know how to test things in-browser, so I have a program called Xampp that simulates a web server. It's not great.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I observed your code and I think you must remove backslash at the end of input tag,that might solve your problem.
Solution:
do this instead the last line code

```
<input type="submit" value='Make a new Account'>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value='Make a new Account'/>
```

Comment: self terminating tags should be terminated such as <input />. His original code works perfectly in every browser available. I would venture to say it is his testing application that has the real issue as it is seeing only the first <form> and submitting it.